# Copying python int value on list?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to solve a problem where I am asked to rotate an NxN matrix by 90 degrees in place. I have written the code. However, I am having problems because python is exchanging references instead of merely values. Could someone please help me figure out how to exchange the value of integer objects instead of exchanging references? I have included my code below:

```
def rotate90(image):
    print image
    n = len(image)
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
             hold = image[i][j]
             hold2 = image[j][n-i-1]
             image2[i][j] = hold2
             image2[j][n-i-1] = hold
    return image


print rotate90([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
```

Comment: In python, primitive data types - like int - aren't passed by reference, but are instead always passed by value.

Comment: I think you are having issues with the `image2[i][j] = hold2` and the line below that as well do `image2[i][j] = hold2[:]` instead

Comment: Is that actually the case? How then does `def f(i): print(type(i)); f(1)` work if it only passes the value?

Comment: You won't get much performance or memory gains by transposing a matrix in-place in Python. Unless it's a part of your assignment, try creating a new matrix, it will simplify things drastically.

Comment: @Sieg no; in Python, *everything* is passed by value, but that value is an object reference (sometimes referred to as "pass by assignment"). There are no *primitive* types, there are *immutable* types.

Comment: If the output you're expecting is `[[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]`, see [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip).

Comment: @jonrsharpe Not sure what the OP wants but rotation of matrix implies that the output must be `[[7,4,1],[8,5,2],[9,6,3]]`. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @BhargavRao perhaps; in which case `map(reversed, zip(*image))` would do it

Comment: @jonrsharpe This is my doubt about SO, should we debug the OPs code or help him with a better one?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I like map/reduce, but in python 3 it needs to wrapped with a `list()` call other wise you return a generator - which is a real pain when writing cross-version code. @Bhargav I tend to agree but some things just pique your curiosity enough to want to fix em :)

Comment: @BhargavRao in a case like this I think a good answer would *explain why* the current code doesn't work, *show how* to fix it and *suggest* ways for broader improvement. Just giving alternative code that does it fails to explain to the OP why their current approach was flawed, leaving them to make the same mistake again later. Having said that, as the OP hasn't posted a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's not totally clear what the issue is.

Answer (score 2):

This function will rotate an NxN list of lists

```
def rotate(m):
    return [list(reversed(ll)) for ll in zip(*m)]
```

Which should work unchanged in 2.7 and 3.4 (dealing with the difference in how generators work)

Use `zip(*m)` to unpack the original list of lists and pass each resulting list as a separate argument to zip. Thus the following

```
l = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
zip(*l)
```

is equivalent to

```
zip([1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9])
```

Comment: Really need to be able to post this kind of thing as a comment. Not expecting this to be accepted as an answer

Comment: Can you explain zip(*m) -- * before m

Comment: Does this actually rotate `m` _in place_, though? It creates a whole new `list` before destroying `m` doesn't it?

Comment: No, but calling it as `m = rotate(m)` gets that effect for you. I usually prefer *not* to modify arguments

Comment: True, but if the OP's array is huge he might prefer _to_ modify it as an argument...

Comment: Using zip, list, reversed, etc has the speed advantage that they are all implemented in C rather than pure python, and the OP is free to modify the answer for their own purposes

Comment: Also, if things get huge this would call out for numpy and a single matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused by some of the answers here: the other answer rotates the list by 180 degrees rather than the 90 requested, and does not do so in place, which is what the OP wanted. So I offer my own solution below:

```
def rotate90(image):
    n = len(image)
    for i in range(n//2):
        for j in range(i, n-i-1):
            e1 = image[i][j]
            e2 = image[j][n-i-1]
            e3 = image[n-i-1][n-j-1]
            e4 = image[n-j-1][i]
            image[i][j] = e4
            image[j][n-i-1] = e1
            image[n-i-1][n-j-1] = e2
            image[n-j-1][i] = e3
```

As in:

```
>>> image = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
>>> rotate90(image)
>>> image
[[7, 4, 1], [8, 5, 2], [9, 6, 3]]
```